# Create a column of unique identifiers based on another column in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

As the title states, I'm trying to create a column in a `data.table` which would act as a unique identifier of another column.  My dataset is a few hundred million observations, but here's a play set and the code I've worked up so far:

```
# I use a key because there are many more columns, but they are irrelevant here
myDT <- data.table(Addy=c("12hig", "12hig", "12hig", "1AbHN", "198aM"),key="Addy")

    Addy
1: 12hig
2: 12hig
3: 12hig
4: 198aM
5: 1AbHN

uniqueDT <- unique(myDT[,list(Addy)]) # is this inefficient?
uniqueDT[,mrpId := seq(1,nrow(uniqueDT),1)]

Addy mrpId
1: 12hig     1
2: 198aM     2
3: 1AbHN     3


myDT[J(uniqueDT)]
    Addy mrpId
1: 12hig     1
2: 12hig     1
3: 12hig     1
4: 198aM     2
5: 1AbHN     3
```

My code above gets the job done, but I don't really know if it's efficient.  Is there a more `data.table`-esque way of doing this?

**Edit:**

You might be wondering why I'm creating unique identifiers from unique identifiers. Well, the idea here is to basically create a hash. The 'Addy' column data are very long strings, and I need to do operations on this data, so I think it better to operate on a smaller number of bytes.

Comment: As to your larger question, if you set `Addy` as your key (which you likely should), I'm a bit skeptical that you'll get much if any speedup by by using an alternative column  containing the very same grouping information. My strong guess (but it is only a guess) is that behind the scenes -- whether they contain very short or very long strings -- any two keyed columns use the same machinery to id, subset, and operate on subgroups of  the data.table.

Comment: Interesting, I'll keep that in mind.  As of right now though, after a few operations in R the data is getting exported to other programs that aren't as memory efficient as `data.table`.

Comment: @frank Yea, Matt Dowle's final edit covers this. However I searched for this question and didn't find that question, or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28910376/is-there-a-way-in-data-table-to-assign-ids-by-group-based-upon-an-identifier?lq=1

Comment: @mrp I don't mean the dupe vote as a criticism; I upvoted your question, too. Good find on that other question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be fast, and is at least a bit more straightforward:

```
myDT[, mrpID:=.GRP, by=Addy]
myDT
    Addy mrpID
1: 12hig     1
2: 12hig     1
3: 12hig     1
4: 198aM     2
5: 1AbHN     3
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from `data.table`, the `base` `factor` class seems to be what you need:

```
myDT[, mrpID:=as.numeric(as.factor(Addy))]
```

Comment: I tried going this route, but running `as.numeric(as.factor())` turned out to be a fairly slow operation.

Comment: Also, when doing something like this, you need to  take special measures to ensure that values returned are in ascending order. (Try this to see what I mean: `as.numeric(as.factor(c("C","B","A")))`.) You can get around that particular problem with `x <- c("C", "B", "A"); as.numeric(factor(x, levels=unique(x)))`